# spring integration :SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method getResponseForSample(javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement)

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

I am new in Spring integration and facing the issue when unmarshalling the SOAP request. I have the below sample xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"
    version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="FFSampleRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Timestamp" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"
                    form="qualified" />
                <xs:element name="SampleType" type="xs:int" form="qualified" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="FFSampleResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Timestamp" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="SampleType" type="xs:int" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="getResponseForSample" type="tns:getResponseForSample" />
    <xs:element name="getResponseForSampleResponse" type="tns:getResponseForSampleResponse" />
    <xs:complexType name="getResponseForSample">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="arg0" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Timestamp" type="xs:string"
                            minOccurs="1" form="qualified" />
                        <xs:element name="SampleType" type="xs:int" form="qualified" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getResponseForSampleResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Timestamp" type="xs:string"
                            minOccurs="1" />
                        <xs:element name="SampleType" type="xs:int" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now I have created the java files using the jaxbmarshaller xjc compiler, below is objectFactory file.other files generated are FFSampleRequest, FFSampleResponse, GetResponseForSample, GetResponseForSampleResponse, package-info. put all these files at

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4-2 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2014.07.07 at 06:00:25 PM GST 
//




import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


  @XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _GetResponseForSample_QNAME = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "getResponseForSample");
    private final static QName _GetResponseForSampleResponse_QNAME = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "getResponseForSampleResponse");
        public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link GetResponseForSample }
     * 
     */
    public GetResponseForSample createGetResponseForSample() {
        return new GetResponseForSample();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link GetResponseForSampleResponse }
     * 
     */
    public GetResponseForSampleResponse createGetResponseForSampleResponse() {
        return new GetResponseForSampleResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link FFSampleRequest }
     * 
     */
    public FFSampleRequest createFFSampleRequest() {
        return new FFSampleRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link FFSampleResponse }
     * 
     */
    public FFSampleResponse createFFSampleResponse() {
        return new FFSampleResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link GetResponseForSample.Arg0 }
     * 
     */
    public GetResponseForSample.Arg0 createGetResponseForSampleArg0() {
        return new GetResponseForSample.Arg0();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link GetResponseForSampleResponse.Return }
     * 
     */
    public GetResponseForSampleResponse.Return createGetResponseForSampleResponseReturn() {
        return new GetResponseForSampleResponse.Return();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link GetResponseForSample }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "getResponseForSample")
    public JAXBElement<GetResponseForSample> createGetResponseForSample(GetResponseForSample value) {
        return new JAXBElement<GetResponseForSample>(_GetResponseForSample_QNAME, GetResponseForSample.class, null, value);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link GetResponseForSampleResponse }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "getResponseForSampleResponse")
    public JAXBElement<GetResponseForSampleResponse> createGetResponseForSampleResponse(GetResponseForSampleResponse value) {
        return new JAXBElement<GetResponseForSampleResponse>(_GetResponseForSampleResponse_QNAME, GetResponseForSampleResponse.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

web.xml file to handle the soap request:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-ws-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and used the below settings in the configuration file for calling the service method for this request:

```
<int:channel id="FFSampleRequestChannel"/>

<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="ws-ffsample-gateway" request-channel="FFSampleRequestChannel" marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller"/>

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.java.MyChannel.model" />
    </bean>

<int:service-activator input-channel="FFSampleRequestChannel">
    <bean class="com.java.MyChannel.serviceImpl.FFSampleImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref = "ffSampleRequest"></constructor-arg>

<bean id="ffSampleRequest" class="com.java.MyChannel.model.FFSampleRequest"></bean>
    <bean id="ffSampleResponse" class="com.java.MyChannel.model.FFSampleResponse"></bean>
```

my soap request hits service class successfully but I am getting the exception.

```
  /**
     * @author Vinay Agrawal
     */
    @XmlRegistry
    public class FFSampleImpl implements FFSampleInterface
    {

        @Autowired
        FFSampleRequest request;
        @Autowired
        FFSampleJdbc ffSampleJdbc;
        public FFSampleImpl() {
        }

        public FFSampleImpl(FFSampleRequest request) {
            super();
            this.request = request;
        }

        @Override
        @PayloadRoot(localPart = "getResponseForSample" , namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
        @ResponsePayload
        public FFSampleResponse getResponseForSample(@RequestPayload FFSampleRequest request){
            List<FFSampleResponse> ffSampleResponse = new ArrayList<FFSampleResponse>();

            return ffSampleResponse ;

        }
    }
```

Soap request is as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getResponseForSample>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>

            <ser:Timestamp>"100"</ser:Timestamp>
            <ser:SampleType>15</ser:SampleType>
         </arg0>
      </ser:getResponseForSample>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I receive the below exception as below:

```
   19:20:34.472 WARN  [tomcat-http--15][org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway] failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
    org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method getResponseForSample(javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) cannot be found on com.java.myChannel.serviceImpl.FFSampleImpl type
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:71)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribablmyChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribablmyChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessagmyChannel.send(AbstractMessagmyChannel.java:255)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:114)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:154)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:75)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:250)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:224)
        at org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway.doInvoke(MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceInboundGateway.invoke(AbstractWebServiceInboundGateway.java:54)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MessageEndpointAdapter.invoke(MessageEndpointAdapter.java:41)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I changed the service method parameter below but when I try to receive the values given in the SOAP message is not binding and I am getting null values for the "SampleType" and "Timestamp".

```
  public class FFSampleImpl implements FFSampleInterface
    {

        @Autowired
        FFSampleRequest request;
        public FFSampleImpl() {
        }

        public FFSampleImpl(FFSampleRequest request) {
            super();
            this.request = request;
        }

        @Override
        @PayloadRoot(localPart = "getResponseForSample" , namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
        @ResponsePayload
        public FFSampleResponse getResponseForSample(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<FFSampleRequest> ffreq){
            FFSampleResponse ffSampleResponse2 = new FFSampleResponse();
            return ffSampleResponse2;

        /*  return FFSampleResponse;*/
        }
```

I am suspecting that the entries that created in the object factory is not correct because feels that I am facing the challenge due to these entries only(below entries). Please let me know if we have any limitations to use jAXBMARSHALLER and xjc compiler also with the spring integration for marshalling/unmarshalling purpose, because I am facing lot of challenges with the soap mapping from xjc generated java objects. Please provide your inpur and let me know where I am missing for the binding of my soap parameters.

```
/**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link GetResponseForSample }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "getResponseForSample")
    public JAXBElement<FFSampleRequest> createGetResponseForSample(FFSampleRequest value) {
        return new JAXBElement<FFSampleRequest>(_GetResponseForSample_QNAME, FFSampleRequest.class, null, value);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link GetResponseForSampleResponse }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "getResponseForSampleResponse")
    public JAXBElement<GetResponseForSampleResponse> createGetResponseForSampleResponse(GetResponseForSampleResponse value) {
        return new JAXBElement<GetResponseForSampleResponse>(_GetResponseForSampleResponse_QNAME, GetResponseForSampleResponse.class, null, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used `JAXBElement`, however it might be usefull.
I generate classes for XSD and mark them as JaxB elements, e.g.:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "feeRequest", propOrder = {
        "billerId",
        "amount"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "feeRequest")
public class FeeReqData {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Long billerId;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Double amount;
}
```

And use `ObjectFactory` only manually and don't rely on that JaxB magic.

This is enough for me to get correct model object based on inbound XML.

From other side, if you use `FFSampleImpl` as a Spring Integration `<service-activator>` there is no reason to mark its methods with Spring-WS annotations.

Comment: Thank you very much Artem. Actually surprised but true that files created by jaxbmarshaller xjc is not always correct. I corrected entries manually in Pojo files and object factory and now this is working fine.